# Academic writing: enumerating properties of which several may apply

Tags: word-usage, lists, writing-advice

In an academic paper I currently say the following:

> State-of-the-art research tackles parts of the problem: security and multi-tenancy solutions exist but require hardware, do not meet shared use security concerns or are not applicable to constrained devices.

What I intend to convey is that these solutions either:

1. require possible hardware

   **and/or**
2. not meet shared-use security concerns

   **and/or**
3. be inapplicable to constrained devices.

That is, at least one of the properties enumerated above applies here, but  others from the list may apply as well. I don’t mean to imply that exactly one and only one of them applies, only that at least one of them applies.

Is my initial idea on how to formulate this sufficiently clear without introducing too many words?

Comment: Hello, Sven.  Your question sounds as if it might be interesting, if you could just give a little more context.  What is the problem to which these are possible solutions?  None of my guesses is obviously the right one.  I have one observation, for what it is worth.  You are using a style of grammar that is increasingly widespread and (by die-hards like me) regrettable.  For want of a better word, I might call it ‘nominal epitheticism’,  by which I mean the use of abstract and other nouns as adjectives.  EG “Security and multi-tenancy solutions”.  It’s in line with current usage but...

Comment: I've added the full sentence. The problem in question is that "Resource-constrained devices are not fully utilized because they cannot support multiple services or do so securely."

Comment: That’s clearer.  My difficulty now is that I cannot see how a ‘security solution’ could possibly be a “possible candidate for discussion if there remained security concerns!

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but the intended meaning is existing security solutions are not encompassing and lack support for a whole range of concerns.
For instance, a wooden door might protect your home from quick unlawful entry by somebody without a key but will not protect against a motivated person with a big sledge hammer.

Comment: In that case, it is as clear as is possible within the limitations of brevity.  I assume your intended audience is expert or at least sufficiently informed.  So you will be picking out a familiar problem.  So the person apologising for density should be me!

Comment: "State-of-the-art research tackles **some or all** (the) parts of the problem:" should take care of it.

Comment: Composition questions better be asked on [writers.se]

Comment: Not 100% sure this is what you intend, but as it stands, it is a mess. "State-of-the-art research tackles part(s) of the problem: security and multi-tenancy solutions exist but may require hardware, may not meet shared use security concerns(,) or may not apply to constrained devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure a poet could do it better justice, but here is a stab at rephrasing. Would also suggest remove hyphen from multitenancy (within the scope of your paper)

> State-of-the-art research addresses only part of the problem. Security and multitenancy solutions exist, but with several challenges which can occur in tandem or in isolation, i.e.; requisite hardware, shared-use security protection, or applicability with constrained devices.

Comment: In a very jargonistic sentence, you might improve readability by dropping the reference to 'state-of-the-art' if you mean 'even the latest research...'

Comment: @JeremyC 100% yes